# Is pagination better than next/preview 20 results?

Tags: seo, pagination

From a SEO perspective. Is it better to show a classic pagination 
[image: classic pagination]

Than "just" previous/next buttons

Comment: Are you suggesting that with "pagination", each page would contain a single result and if you had Next/Previous links only then each page would contain 20 results?

Answer (score 4):

It's a good question. Unfortunately, there is no correct answer as each option has its trade offs and you need to decide based on your use case.

1. Previous/Next Links - The major problem with this implementation is crawling of your website as page 20 can be at a very deep level from homepage. Also, for user, the navigation might be problematic. I would however, prefer this approach if there are not many pages say if the page count is only 4-6.
2. Paginated - It somehow would alleviate the problem of deeper pages by linking deeper pages from the front page itself. However, if you have too many pages and you list all the pages, there can be just too many links which might act as a red flag from seo point of view.

For large page counts, I personally like a balancing act by putting 6 or 8 links for pagination e.g. if you are on page n, I would show first,...n-2,n-1, n+1, n+2,...last page. This way, the pages would be easy to navigate and easily accessible by crawlers as well.